# Bootstrap 5 How to apply different justifications to elements inside div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to get a layout like the following:

[image]

I am using the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/800/600"></a>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <p>Test1</p>
                    <p>Test2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Button1</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Button2</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Button3</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am having problems in the buttons section, to justify the 3 of them to the bottom, and button3 to the right of the layout.

Any idea how to apply different justifications to the elements inside a div?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="btn-group col-auto me-auto">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Button1</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Button2</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group d-flex justify-content-end col-auto">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Button3</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Update**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/800/600"></a>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="row mb-auto">
                    <p>Test1</p>
                    <p>Test2</p>
                </div>

                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="btn-group col-auto me-auto">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Button1</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Button2</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="btn-group d-flex justify-content-end col-auto">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Button3</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>                

            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/n0bod2m6/

Comment: It works for button3. But it does not move all the buttons to the bottom of the div like in my picture